# Ruby on Rails map.root doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the root of my application to route to a default controller.  From what I read, this should be possible with something like this at the bottom of my routes.rb file:

```
map.root :controller => 'albums'
```

or perhaps even:

```
map.home  '', :controller => 'albums'
```

However, when I try navigating to http://myhost:8000/, I just see the rails welcome page.  I am restarting the application with the following command after making the change to routes.rb and before testing it:

```
sudo mongrel_cluster_ctl restart
```

Here is some more possibly pertinent environment information:

```
% rails -v
Rails 2.3.3

% ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
```

I am sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't see what it is.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you deleted the static `public/index.html` page that Rails creates? If this is still in your app it will be shown instead of the root page you defined in the routes.

Answer (score 12):

Delete the public/index.html file.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something simple!

Answer (score 3):

```
map.root :controller => 'albums'
```

Is the correct syntax.

A few things to try:

- delete index.html from public.
- Look at the output of "rake routes", do you see something along the lines of:

```
root   /  {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"index"}
```

- Are you 100% sure the right cluster is being restarted: try running script/server and navigating to root on port 3000

Answer (score 1):

Routes at the end of `routes.rb` are the last to get used, therefore you may want to try with '`map.root...`' at the top of your `routes.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I was scratching my head for a while now.
Deleting public/index.html file did the glitch for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different problem.  I've set up a  map.root entry and it works with mongrel.  However when I use apache2 as the web server with Passenger module I get a '500' error.  If I re-instate my /public/index.html then it works under apache2.

I have tried to go directly as:

http:///home/index

This also gives me the same '500' error.

Please can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Hi

I found someone else who had had the same problem. Turns out that Passenger is running in production mode whilst my app was in development mode.

I put Passenger into development mode by adding the following line to my Virtual Hosts file

RailsEnv = development

Restarted Apache and it all works!!

Phew!

Purvez

Comment: If you have a new issue, please post it as a new question.  You can ask a new question by clicking the "Ask Question button in the top-right corner of the page.  Also, if you find an answer to a question (even if it is your own question, you can then post it as an answer, rather than editing your original question.